# Clean and build java project without eclipse GUI using another java program

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ant

I am writing a program that needs to run JUnit tests that are located in an external project.  That external project needs to be cleaned and built to ensure that the JUnit tests are run correctly.  I can't require the user to go in and clean and build manually, so I need to automate this process. It needs to be done inside of a java program.

I was thinking I could possibly use ant, but then I would have to potentially call an external shell script to clean and build the project. I would prefer to do it all in one project, but if ant is the only way to go, please let me know.

I can't require the user to check the **build automatically** option in eclipse, because the projects we work with are really big and take a lot of time to build.

How do I automate the eclipse process of cleaning and building a project in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am running the project using gradle, I was able to figure out and automate the process of cleaning and building with gradle by only requiring the user to run another project rather than use eclipse.